# Unity-Character not spawning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having trouble in spawning a character in Unity. This is my LoadCharacter script. The Debug.Log confirms that selectedCharacter has the expected value

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadCharacter : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] characterPrefabs;
    public Transform spawnPoint;

    void Start()
    {
        int selectedCharacter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("selectedCharacter");
        GameObject prefab = characterPrefabs[selectedCharacter];
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Debug.Log(prefab.name);
    }
}
```

and below are printscreens of the scene where I want to spawn the character

[image: my game manager]

[image: my spawnpoint(white circle)]

[image: play mode]

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you print screen the inspector with the spawned character?

Comment: Other thing is screenshots display the editor not while it's running.

Comment: Are you sure the prefab doesn’t show in the Hierarchy

Comment: @Omar Abdel Bari I don't have an inspector for the spawned character

Comment: @BugFinder the prefab is appearing in game mode hierarchy

Comment: Your characters are capsules of size 1, map appears to be much bigger, did you try making your capsules super large to see if perhaps it's just too small?

Comment: So. Your problem could be layer orders. The reality is. He is there. You just can’t see him either because he’s off screen or too small or behind the map etc

Comment: He is spawning off the screen

Comment: My problem is the spawn point. If I leave at 0,0,0 my character spawns off screen. If I put values like for example -150,-157,50 he spawns in the Middle of the map

Comment: The problem could be that the spawn point relative position should be adjusted so it is closer to the camera. I have only done 3d projects in unity but my guess would be to adjust the z value. Since you said setting the position of the characters to -150,-157,50  works I would try, one by one, to set spawn relative position in inspector as follows: x = -10, y = -10, z = 10 and likely one of those 3 will fix your problem.

Comment: found the problem. My GameManager wasn´t at 0,0,0

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because of you didn't set a parent for your Instantiated object. Your SpawnPoint is a child of a parent but instantiated object is not. That's may be the problem.

If you don't know how to do it, you can read the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) right here.

Comment: Actually the problem is the position the spawnPoint. If I put it at 0,0,0 my character will spawn at 150.9,157.6,-49.6

Comment: He doesn't have to set a parent to the character object but he may need to do additional computations to get the position right.

Comment: @FábioPires Keep in mind the position and rotation that appears in the inspector is local rotation  (relative to the parent) by default. Also, are your characters affected by gravity?

Comment: I think they aren't affected by gravity

Comment: You would know simply seeing if there is any changes in position/rotation of the character game object in the inspector as the game is running.